# Spark Streaming 2.0.1 - Datasets and RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, linear-regression

I am a beginner for spark streaming and trying with streaming linear regression example using scala. So when I searched I have found lots of examples for streaming machine learning algorithms using RDDs. But isn't it possible to use datasets (introduced in spark 2.0.1) for streaming instead of RDDs. Is there any way to verify whether the code is using RDDs or Datasets?I have posted my code below. Any help appreciated.

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scopt.OptionParser
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ DataFrame, SparkSession }
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.document.Import
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import java.lang.Boolean

object LinearRegressionExample {

  case class Params(
    input: String = null,
    testInput: String = "",
    dataFormat: String = "libsvm",
    regParam: Double = 0.0,
    elasticNetParam: Double = 0.0,
    maxIter: Int = 100,
    tol: Double = 1E-6,
    fracTest: Double = 0.2) extends AbstractParams[Params]

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val defaultParams = Params()
    val parser = new OptionParser[Params]("LinearRegressionExample") {
      head("LinearRegressionExample: an example Linear Regression with Elastic-Net app.")
      opt[Double]("regParam")
    .text(s"regularization parameter, default: ${defaultParams.regParam}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(regParam = x))
      opt[Double]("elasticNetParam")
    .text(s"ElasticNet mixing parameter. For alpha = 0, the penalty is an L2 penalty. " +
      s"For alpha = 1, it is an L1 penalty. For 0 < alpha < 1, the penalty is a combination of " +
      s"L1 and L2, default: ${defaultParams.elasticNetParam}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(elasticNetParam = x))
  opt[Int]("maxIter")
    .text(s"maximum number of iterations, default: ${defaultParams.maxIter}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(maxIter = x))
  opt[Double]("tol")
    .text(s"the convergence tolerance of iterations, Smaller value will lead " +
      s"to higher accuracy with the cost of more iterations, default: ${defaultParams.tol}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(tol = x))
  opt[Double]("fracTest")
    .text(s"fraction of data to hold out for testing. If given option testInput, " +
      s"this option is ignored. default: ${defaultParams.fracTest}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(fracTest = x))
  opt[String]("testInput")
    .text(s"input path to test dataset. If given, option fracTest is ignored." +
      s" default: ${defaultParams.testInput}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(testInput = x))
  opt[String]("dataFormat")
    .text("data format: libsvm (default), dense (deprecated in Spark v1.1)")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(dataFormat = x))
  arg[String]("<input>")
    .text("input path to labeled examples")
    .required()
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(input = x))
}

    parser.parse(args, defaultParams) match {
      case Some(params) => run(params)
      case _            => sys.exit(1)
    }
      }

  def run(params: Params): Unit = {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("LinearRegressionExample with $params")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName(s"LinearRegressionExample with $params")
      .getOrCreate()

    println(s"LinearRegressionExample with parameters:\n$params")

    // Load training and test data and cache it.
    val (training: DataFrame, test: DataFrame) =     DecisionTreeExample.loadDatasets(params.input,
      params.dataFormat, params.testInput, "regression", params.fracTest)

    val lir = new LinearRegression()
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setRegParam(params.regParam)
      .setElasticNetParam(params.elasticNetParam)
      .setMaxIter(params.maxIter)
      .setTol(params.tol)

    // Train the model
    val startTime = System.nanoTime()
    val lirModel = lir.fit(training)
    val elapsedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e9
    println(s"Training time: $elapsedTime seconds")

    // Print the weights and intercept for linear regression.
    println(s"Weights: ${lirModel.coefficients} Intercept:     ${lirModel.intercept}")

    println("Training data results:")
    DecisionTreeExample.evaluateRegressionModel(lirModel, training, "label")
    println("Test data results:")
    DecisionTreeExample.evaluateRegressionModel(lirModel, test, "label")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you are actually using `ssc` in the program? when you use Spark Streaming Context, it returns the DStream( which is nothing but combination of multiple RDDs). If you want to work with Dataset, you can convert the RDD to DataSet.

Comment: @Shankar Just found that all the current streaming algorithms use RDDs. (spark 2.0.1) But I need to use datasets.What is the best way to do that.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/SqlNetworkWordCount.scala) could be a good example for you. There is also a way to use "streaming datasets" with [structured streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html), but its a alpha version.

Comment: @SimonSchiff Sorry for interrupting you.Your help is really appreciated.Would it be possible to use this streaming datasets in structured streaming for machine learning algorithms also?

Comment: The streaming datasets are the same as in spark sql. But at the moment they are limited in their functionality. At the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/a-deep-dive-into-structured-streaming) from Databricks at Slide 26 you can see it is/will be possible.